# Is it ok to switch to logarithms when testing divergence of sequences involving a sum of exponentials? E.g $x_n = 5^n - 4^n \to \ln5^n - \ln4^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponential-function

Consider the following sequence:

$$
x_n = 5^n - 4^n
$$

I'm wondering whether it is ok to switch from comparing exponents to comparing logarithms. Here is what I mean:

Instead of $5^n - 4^n$ compare:

$$
\ln5^n - \ln4^n = n(\ln5 - \ln4) = n\ln{5\over4}
$$

Which is clearly divergent. Is that true that if the expression involving logarithms diverges then the expression with exponentials also diverges?

**Update**

As pointed in the comments it's not very clear what kinds of sequences are taken into consideration. Those are in the form of:

$$
x_n = a_1^n + a_2^n + \dots + a_k^n
$$

Where $a_k$ is some constant term and the number of terms is limited by $k$.

Comment: I don't think you can do it in the way the you did it. However, you could try $$ \ln(5^n-4^n) = \ln(5^n(1-(4/5)^n)) = n\ln(5) + \ln(1-(4/5)^n), $$ which also clearly diverges since the first term is unbounded while the second term converges to $0$, and then argue by comparison since $\ln(x) \leq x$ for $x>0$.

Comment: It's not clear from the question exactly which kinds of sequences are under consideration here. If the question is "For certain sequences $(a_n), (b_n)$, does the divergence of $\log a_n - \log b_n$ imply divergence of $a_n - b_n$?", then what form are you asking of $a_n, b_n$?

Comment: @Travis in particular I'm interested in the sequences of the form $x_n = a_1^n + a_2^n + \dots + a_n^n$. Where $a_n$ is a some given number (constant). It worked for the case above and I wonder whether this applies for other sequences of that kind

Comment: @Travis also, should I rephrase the question?

Comment: @roman So the number of terms in your sequence is increasing? (You wrote $a_n^n$, i.e. $n$ appears both in the index and in the exponent.)

Comment: @Sobi Thanks for pointing out. I was meaning a fixed number of terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$1, 1+1, 1+1+1, ...$ diverges but $\ln 1, \ln 1 + \ln 1, \ln 1 + \ln 1 + \ln 1...$ is converges.

There's really no comparitive relationship between $a + b$ and $\ln a + \ln b$ especially as $a + b = (a+ k) +(b-k)$ and $\ln a + \ln b$ need not have any predictable comparison to $\ln (a+k) + \ln (b-k) = M*\ln a + \frac 1M \ln b$ for any arbitrary constant $M$.  As we can manipulate $M$ to get just about any value there's really nothing we can conclude.

Even comparing $a + b$ to $\ln(a + b)$ should be taken with a grain of salt as we have to prove not only that both increasing and decreasing is maintained in conversion but that boundedness is as well.

So as $\ln$ is *not* distributive attempting *any* comparison of $a + b$ to $\ln a + \ln b$ should set off many red lights and should not set off any green ones.

Comment: I mean.  Why should $\ln a + \ln b$ be any more valid a comparison to $a + b$ than $\sin a + \sin b$ is?

Comment: I get what you're saying, but at least $\ln$ is injective. The sum of values of $\sin$, as for example $\sin(0)=\sin(2\pi)$, is more easily seen to have no bearing on the sum of its inputs.

Comment: $\ln (x)$ is injective but  $f(x,y) = \ln x + \ln y$ sure as shooting isn't.

Answer (score 1):

This is not ok, you can make this here
$$\log(ab)=\log(a)+\log(b)$$
$$\log\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)=\log(a)-\log(b)$$
for $$a,b>0$$